# Enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform, geocoding, google-cloud-billing

I want to retrieve address from lat long coords. I have created project in google console. Added Billing information and enabled the geocoding api services. But still when i make this request i am getting the below error

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=41.89,12.49&key=xxxx

You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable

Comment: Is that billing account associated with the key?

Comment: https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-automate-project-creation-using-gcloud-4e71d9a70047 might help

Answer (score 66):

I was also Facing the same issue, Billing is enabled and is linked to the project but I was getting the same Error.

After Spending enough time on this issue, I understood that the type of my billing account is ***"Google Cloud Platform"***, but it should be of type : ***"Google Maps Platform"***

You can see the type of your billing account on the right side of Billing Overview as in the image:

[image]

So please check if your Billing type is ***"Google Maps Platform"***, if not create a new Billing Account with ***"Google Maps Platform"*** as type and link your project to this Billing Account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this saved me a lot of time. Few things go undetected when configuring something.

Comment: I think this should be marked as correct answer. This solved my problem.

Comment: I am not geting that enabled google services option in my page!!

Comment: Thanks, I'm facing the same problem. But I'd like to ask that if I enable a new billing account for Google Maps Platform then will there be any price for it. any initial price?

Comment: You do not say how i can add that type?

Answer (score 34):

Most of us are getting this response/error

```
{
   "error_message" : "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at <br>https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started",
   "predictions" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

**If you will read this answer throughly you'll be able to sort out this issue.**

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63572457/2850120).
You'd have to create a separate billing account in order to use Google Map APIs because google map bills in USD currency instead of your native currency.

**Solution(3 step)**

1. create a new billing account.
2. create a new project and associate it with above billing.
3. enable Map API and create a new API key. that's it.

**Step1**: create a new billing account, you can use this link https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/create and Choose ***Google Map Platform*** from the dropdown.

[image]

**Step2:** create a new project using this link https://console.cloud.google.com/projectcreate and use billing account created above.

[image]

**Step3:** Now you can enable particular API and you're good to go. **That's it.**

Comment: Billing asking for card number and all. I want to use it for free. How can I use that ?

Comment: not possible, card is required even if it don't charge

Comment: Thank You very much, didnt know we had to create a new project with billing account

Comment: I cannot select this when creating a new account.

Comment: can you share the screenshot @MartinBraun ?

Comment: @RishabhAgrawal Thanks for your reply, I got it working. Your answer is outdated, your billing account can be used on Maps and Cloud at the same time. There is no difference anymore, hence [you cannot select the type of billing account anymore](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/create). The reason why it didn't work for me was that I had an old API key of another account that was still active but without billing, that's all.

Comment: @MartinBraun good to hear that you've sorted the issue.

Comment: they ask for a phone number :(

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that the API key you are using to authenticate the request is from a project that has an active billing account. If not, your requests will fail and if you are using Javascript API, your map will get the "**Degraded experience**".

Below are some of the links we have that could be helpful in your use case.

- [Managing your billing accounts](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account)
- [Modify a project's billing settings](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project)
- [Viewing your cost trends with billing reports](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports)

Once everything is set up, you can always file a support case via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support in order to open personalized communication channel whenever you are encountering issues with our product.

Thank you and hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

1. Go back to the billing account and see if something went wrong with your credit card. Credit cards are validated asynchronously.
2. Go to the GCP Console and verify that your billing account is assigned to the project.
3. In the GCP Console check for past due amounts.

After you assign/modify a credit card, wait. The process is not instant in (re)authorizing billing for your account.

Comment: I'm just testing so don't care about the 'development purposes only' overlay. I don't want to set up a billing account (yet at least) so how to disable the popup warning?

Comment: it doesn't work man. The Google Maps Platform is no longer there and I'm still having the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: We were able to find the issues with our CC and updated the CC to pay, again. How long do we have to wait until the process will work again?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I was doing everything correct.
then I found this link

[Gmp india faq](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-india-faq)

The problem was Google maps billing doesn't support INR Currency.

Please check if your currency compatible with Google Maps billing platform otherwise create new billing account with USD currency.

Thanks!

You may find this link helpful

[Modify a project billing settings](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#change_the_billing_account_for_a_project)

Answer (score 3):

I have had similar problem, when I have created a free tire payment account and I was not able to create a Windows VM as thesse are paid.
To fix I have "upgraded" the free tier payment account. It was confusing because the payment account has had enabled a valid payment method and linked to the project but it was not working.

There is a button to **upgrade** the free tier payment account, on the account dashboard page.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still struggling , my case was that i have reached a maximum of projects for the same billing account and  for some reason i couldnt create a new one as mentioned above , for  that after a lot of reasearch i found that i could disable billing for some project so i can use it in new ones :
1- go to the link https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/projects
2- click on the three dots for the first projects (the billing is enbale for those projects).
3-disable  one of them
4- enable the billing for your new project  and you are good to go !

however still not sure why i could only enable this for just 3 project , i think it is not a lot !

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who enabled their billing account through the link in the error message but still get the error, or can't find "Enabled google service" as someone else suggested, simply just delete your browsers cache and try again.

Comment: Not working, after deleting cache as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```bash
gcloud alpha billing accounts list --format json
# ^^ find an active billing account then
ACCOUNT_ID='0XYXYX-XYXYXY-XYXYXY'
gcloud beta billing projects link $PROJECTNAME --billing-account $ACCOUNT_ID
# ensure it says "billingEnabled: true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing one more step. You also need to add that billing account to that project to gain access.

**NOTE**: Do not disable and reenable your project it will have some side effect in your project and some stuff are not recoverable. It is mention in documentation.

Here the [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project).

[image]